# Constructor of another bean which is used for action listener is being called from a page

Tags: user-interface, jsf-2, richfaces

i have a link in a page which redirects to another xhtml page. In the current page, different backing bean is used. Whenever i click on the link to redirect to another page, the constructor of the bean being used in current page is called.

Is it the expected behavior?

Comment: That will happen if you incorrectly use POST (command links) for page-to-page navigation instead of GET (output links). Was you indeed doing so?

Comment: Will the constructor of a bean be called if i'm using one of its methods as action listener in the xhtml page?

Comment: It looks like you don't understand POST vs GET in basic HTTP. Which answer do you find more helpful in better understanding that? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4317684 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/15521451